# Search and show specific content after button clicked using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to build search filter with jQuery. I am able to search word and show specific content when a user type text in text box.

**But I want to start search after Search button is clicked.**

here is code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9yw9yjx/)

```js
(function($) {
  jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) {
    return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
  };

  function listFilter(header, list) {
    $(list).find('p').hide();
    var form = $("<form>").attr({
        "class": "filterform",
        "action": "#"
      }),
      input = $("<input>").attr({
        "class": "filterinput",
        "type": "text"
      }),
      search = $("<input>").attr({
        "class": "filterbutton",
        "type": "button",
        "name": "btn1",
        "value": "Search"
      });

    $(form).append(input).appendTo(header);

    $(input).on('input', function() {
      var filter = $(this).val();

      $(list).find('p').hide();

      if (filter) {
        $(list).find("p:Contains(" + filter + ")").show();
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    listFilter($("#header"), $("#list"));
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h1 id="header">Collection</h1>
<div id="list">

  <div id='p1'>
    <p>First Paragraph</p>
    <p>Abbot and Costello - Africa Screams</p>
  </div>

  <div id='p2'>
    <p>Second Paragraph</p>
    <p>Abbot and Costello - Frank/Meet</p>
  </div>

  <div id='p3'>
    <p>Third Paragraph</p>
    <p>addin</p>
  </div>

  <div id='p4'>
    <p>Forth Paragraph</p>
    <p>Begins</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no button in your example?!?

Comment: no, I have tried to build but it isn't working. you can see in code with name search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the Search button and call the filter on click event.

```
$("<input>").attr({"class":"filterbutton","type":"button","name":"btn1","value":"Search"});

    $(form).append(input).appendTo(header);
    $(form).append(search).appendTo(header);

    $(search).on('click', function () {
      var filter = $(input).val();

      $(list).find('p').hide();

      if(filter) {
        $(list).find("p:Contains("+filter+")").show();
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    listFilter($("#header"), $("#list"));
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved, append the button, listen to the click !!

```js
(function($) {
  jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) {
    return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
  };

  function listFilter(header, list) {
    $(list).find('p').hide();
    var form = $("<form>").attr({
        "class": "filterform",
        "action": "#"
      }),
      input = $("<input>").attr({
        "class": "filterinput",
        "type": "text"
      }),
      search = $("<input>").attr({
        "class": "filterbutton",
        "type": "button",
        "name": "btn1",
        "value": "Search"
      });

    $(form).append(input).append(search).appendTo(header);

    $(document).on('click', '.filterbutton', function() {
      var filter = $('.filterinput').val();

      $(list).find('p').hide();

      if (filter) {
        $(list).find("p:Contains(" + filter + ")").show();
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    listFilter($("#header"), $("#list"));
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<title>Some Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1 id="header">Collection</h1>
  <div id="list">

    <div id='p1'>
      <p>First Paragraph</p>
      <p>Abbot and Costello - Africa Screams</p>
    </div>

    <div id='p2'>
      <p>Second Paragraph</p>
      <p>Abbot and Costello - Frank/Meet</p>
    </div>

    <div id='p3'>
      <p>Third Paragraph</p>
      <p>addin</p>
    </div>

    <div id='p4'>
      <p>Forth Paragraph</p>
      <p>Begins</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of triggering on the input event of the `<input type="text />` using:

```
$(input).on('input', function() {
```

Trigger on the click of the button using:

```
$(search).on('click', function() {
```

Then change this:

```
var filter = $(this).val()
```

to this:

```
var filter = $(input).val()
```

so that the user's typed text will be read correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question, but would change `$(input).on('input'` to `$(search´).on('click` get you any closer? Instead of getting `$(this).val()`; you will then have to use `$(input).val();` to get the correct value to search from

Answer (score 0):

**solved your issue plese check this code it may help you better recoded your jsfiddle code according to your problem**

```
    <title>Some Title</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <h1 id="header">Collection</h1>

    <div id="list">

    <div id='p1'>
    <p>First Paragraph</p>
    <p>Abbot and Costello - Africa Screams</p>
    </div>

    <div id='p2'>
    <p>Second Paragraph</p>
    <p>Abbot and Costello - Frank/Meet</p>
    </div>

    <div id='p3'>
    <p>Third Paragraph</p>
    <p>addin</p>
    </div>

    <div id='p4'>
    <p>Forth Paragraph</p>
    <p>Begins</p>
    </div>

    </div>
    </body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
      jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
        return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
      };

      function listFilter(header, list) {
        $(list).find('p').hide();
        var form = $("<form>").attr({"class":"filterform","action":"#"}),
            input = $("<input>").attr({"class":"filterinput","type":"text"}),
            search = $("<input>").attr({"class":"filterbutton","type":"button","name":"btn1","value":"Search"});

        $(form).append(search).appendTo(header);
    $(search).on('click', function () {
          var filter = $(input).val();

          $(list).find('p').hide();

          if(filter) {
            $(list).find("p:Contains("+filter+")").show();
          }
        });
      }

      $(document).ready(function () {
        listFilter($("#header"), $("#list"));
      });
    }(jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: I think you missed the bit where the existing script appends a button; it doesn't need the new `#show` element in the HTML.

Comment: thanks @MattSach - i have edited code again according to your query